# Android repeated Service - onCreate called once, onStartCommand called many

Tags: android, android-service, locationmanager

I followed the basic android documentation to implement a `Service`, triggered repeatedly by `AlarmManager` every 40 seconds. Inside the service I register GPS listener, and if I don't get fix within 30 seconds I call `stopSelf()`, this in order to avoid 2 "concurrent" services running together. However if I do have fix within less then 30 seconds, I perform some logic and after I done I call `stopSelf()` - Assuming it all will take less then 40 seconds so again I have no issues of "concurrent" services running...

When I log print the order of execution of various Service methods it doesn't make any sense:

1. `onCreate` is called only once, while `onStartCommand` is triggered every 40 seconds.
2. The GPS is never fixed, maybe the fact that the hosting `Activity` also registered and do have GPS fix interfere here? (I testing outdoors and the activity does get fix)

This is my implementation - Pretty much straightforward googles android documentation:

```
public class DirectionService extends Service implements Constants {

private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private LocationListener mLocationListeners;
private Context mContext;
private Looper mServiceLooper;
private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;  //not binding
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();
    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
    Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
    msg.arg1 = startId;
    mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    return START_STICKY;
}

//Handler that receives messages from the thread
private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {

    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    /**
     * The real work done after we have (first) fixed location and from there we stop the service.
     * Therefore we pass the start id.
     */
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            mLocationListeners = new LocationListener(msg.arg1);
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, GPS_UPDATE_TIME, 0, mLocationListeners);
            mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(mGPSStatusListener);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            stopSelf(msg.arg1);
        }
        //Start timer for GPS to get fix location. Else we might have new concurrent instance of service
        new CountDownTimer(30000, 15000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

            public void onFinish() {
                stopSelf(msg.arg1);
            }

        }.start();
    }

}

GpsStatus.Listener mGPSStatusListener = new GpsStatus.Listener() {
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        switch (event)
        {
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) != null) {
                        isGpsFixed = true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {

    private int startId;

    public LocationListener(int startId) {
        this.startId = startId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (isGpsFixed == true && location.getLongitude() != 0.0 && location.getLatitude() != 0.0 && isAlreadySentToCheck == false) {
            isAlreadySentToCheck = true;
            startLogic(startId);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}

private void startLogic(final int startId) {
    //...
    stopSelf(startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        try {
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners);
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: A service is a singleton class. only one instance of a given service will be running at any given time. You do not need to complexify your logic. 

If call is made to an already running service, then **onStartCommand()** will be called. That is why you are getting repeated triggers to that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your service running many time because of start_sticky

if your service is killed by Android due to low memory, and Android clears some memory, then...

STICKY: ...Android will restart your service, because that particular flag is set.

NOT_STICKY: ...Android will not care about starting again, because the flag tells Android it shouldn't bother.

REDELIVER_INTENT: ...Android will restart the service AND redeliver the same intent to onStartCommand() of the service, because, again, of the flag.

suggest to your start_not_sticky

Comment: So actually you suggesting my service always killed by the OS... What about the GPS listener? Should be problems?